# how to create a quickpick similar to vscode theme selector

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

am trying to create a quick-pick that execute a command as you go up/down, similar to how you preview a theme.

i've read the [api docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#QuickPickOptions) but i couldn't find what am after so any help is appreciated.

here is what i currently have

```
commands.registerCommand('terminal_themes.apply', async () => {
    let items = themes.map((item) => item.name)

    // change this to update on up&down
    // instead of on selection
    window.showQuickPick(items).then((selection) => {
        if (!selection) {
            return
        }

        // do something with selection
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform some action when the user changes the selection, use the [`onDidSelectItem` option](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#QuickPickOptions) for `showQuickPick`.

```js
commands.registerCommand('terminal_themes.apply', async () => {
    let items = themes.map((item) => item.name)

    window.showQuickPick(items, {
        onDidSelectItem: (item) => {
           // do something with item
        }
    }).then((selection) => {
        // User made final selection
        if (!selection) {
            return
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: many thanx, is there a chance you can post the link to the theme selection source code ?